# Can I make add "display:none" to a HTML element via PHP?

Tags: theming

In my theme on Drupal 7.50 there is a #banner element just beneath a #menu element. The *banner* CSS styles are `{border-bottom:5px solid blue}`. The problem is that sometimes the #banner element is empty and this causes problems with the layout.

Is there a way to add `display:none` to #banner when the banner is empty, using PHP?

Answer (score 2):

If there is no banner there is no reason to output the banner div. Assuming the banner is in a region by itself you can fix this in the page template (page.tpl.php) where the region is printed.

Example:

```
<?php if ($page['banner_region']): ?>
<div id="banner">
  <?php print render($page['banner_region']); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

A workaround would be to apply the border to the actual banner, e.g. the image. In that way the border will only show up if there is an image.

Example:

```
#banner img {
  border-bottom: 5px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: I used your workaround and put the line on the content in #banner. But there could be a reason for an other time to do it in php. #banner is a region by itself. Does your php exemple apply on that in the way that if the region is empty it will not be visible at all?

Comment: Yes. The if-statement makes sure the region is only printed if there is content assigned to it.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to set a minimum height on #banner. That way when #banner is empty of content, there will still be a space between #menu and the border. This solution does not require you to involve PHP at all.

```
#banner {
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The problem is there will be an extra line. But simple it is. Thanks.